# Lazy loading of images with graceful degradation (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Consider a HTML page with a bunch of  tags each with their own content. I want to transform each  tag to a slide in a slideshow powered by JavaScript. Each  tag can contain images and they should be lazy loaded in this slideshow. I don't want all images to load at once.

On the other hand, users with no JavaScript enabled and search engines should just the see markup and all the images. How do I avoid images from loading when JavaScript is enabled, and how do I make sure images are loaded when no JavaScript is enabled?

One way would be to replace all images with this format:

```
<img src="" data-src="myimage.png">
```

The problem with that solution is there's no graceful degradation.

Instead, I have to do:

```
<img src="myimage.png">
```

The problem with that is that you can't prevent the browser from loading all of the images in the HTML page. I've tried to modify the HTML in several ways when the document is ready. For example, replace all src attributes in images with data-src, empty the entire body and so on.

Do I really have to sacrifice graceful degradation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I looked at the referenced article (seroundtable.com/archives/022411.html).  It seemed to me that the content INSIDE the noscript tag could be considered suspect, not the entire document.  Since you are discussing two different representations of the same content, one inside and one outside noscript tags, this does not look to be a cause of concern and the answered below are valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method might be to duplicate the image tags enclosed in a `<noscript>` tag and using their `src` attribute. Above or below that, you could have the same tags with the custom `data-src` attribute, detect and lazy-load them with Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely a valid solution. My concern is, however, that <noscript> is bad SEO. See this link: http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/022411.html

Answer (score 2):

You could include both versions:

```
<img src="" data-src="myimage.png">
<noscript>
  <img src="myimage.png">
</noscript>
```

Might be good to relate the separate `<img>` tags there so that your JavaScript code can keep them in sync. For example:

```
<img src="" class='lazy' data-master="myimage">
<noscript>
  <img id="myimage" class='super-sized interesting' src="myimage.png">
</noscript>
```

Then your JS  code can make sure that the "scripty" images pick up the classes etc so that you don't have to manually keep the two versions updated (pardon the jQuery example; of course you'd do this however you want):

```
$('img.lazy').each(function() {
  var $lazy = $(this),
    master = $('#' + $lazy.data('master'))[0];

    $lazy.src(master.src);
    $lazy.className += master.className;
    // etc
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that elaborate answer! As I said to Steve it's definitely a valid solution. I'm a bit concerned with regards to SEO. It might not be a problem as long as we're not talking about links and only images. See this link: http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/022411.html